# Querying Shared Google Calendar in Objective C using Google API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api, google-api-objc-client

Have searched for any help regarding subject. I do not need OAuth, as the calendar is shared to the public. 
I'd really just like to get all upcoming events, and display them in a table in an iPhone app. As I have zero experience using the API, and very little in coding in Objective C, i find it very hard translating the example in the Google API, which is made for MAC OSX, to iOS. Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Calendar in Objective C use these links...

https://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/

http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/